# How to use a button to control material ui v5 datepicker dialog open/close?

Tags: material-ui

In my react app, I would like to control open/close of a material ui v5 Datepicker by clicking an icon button:

```
  function handleShowCalendar() {
    setState({ showCalendar: true })
  }
<TextField
              {...params}
              autoFocus={props.autoFocus}
              fullWidth
              placeholder="Enter a task..."
              variant="outlined"
              size="small"
              InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                onKeyUp: handleKeyUp,
                endAdornment: addTodo.isLoading ? (
                  <Box position="absolute" top={10} right={10}>
                    <CircularProgress size={16} />
                  </Box>
                ) : (
                  <Box position="absolute" top={-4} right={0}>
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={handleShowCalendar}
                      disabled={state.text.length <= 0}
                    >
                      <CalendarToday />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>
                ),
              }}
            />


...
      <DatePicker
        open={state.showCalendar}
        value={state.due}
        onChange={handleChangeDate}
        onClose={() => setState({ showCalendar: false })}
        disableHighlightToday
        // DialogProps={{ sx: { postition: "inline" } }}
        renderInput={(params) => <Fragment {...params} />}
        showToolbar={true}
        ToolbarComponent={() => (
          <AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography variant="h6">Due Date</Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        )}
      />
    </Fragment>
```

The problem is the position of the Datepicker is always at the top left corner. Can anyone help why the Datepicker won't show like inline, what I am missing in above code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to the question in the title, it seems that the code you have posted does open and close the `DatePicker`.

It sounds like the second question is the one that needs answering, whether it will show "inline".

It seems that the "absolute" position of the `Box` surrounding the `IconButton` and the hardcoded `top` and `right` values are preventing the borders of the DatePicker from being inside of the `TextField`.

[Here's a Code Sandbox illustrating a `DatePicker` within a `TextField`.](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-dawn-bgj0ss?file=/src/App.js)

If you would like to clarify the positioning you prefer, please do so.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I will repost a new question. I think my problem is in my DatePicker I put "dummy" component in the render input. I don't want to have textfield, just want the calendar.